# Converting Logstash config to NiFi: NiFi equivalent to Logstash 'kv' filter

Tags: logstash, apache-nifi

I'm tasked to convert our logstash configuration over to NiFi. Looking at our logstash config, there is a kv filter which takes your message and breaks the key value pairs into new attributes. I'm wanting to do the same thing in NiFi, but not sure the best way to do this in nifi. Is NiFi able to do this?

Example 1

**Input**

node=93266aa type=OPTTYPE systemcall=44 success=yes exit=40 a0=6 a1=7f31a21a77e0 a2=28 a3=0 items=0 ppid=9521 pid=2547

**Output**

{
"node" : "93266aa", "type":"OPTTYPE", "systemcall":"44", "success":"yes", "exit":"40", "a0":"6",  "a1":"7f31a21a77e0", "a2":"28", "a3":"0", "items":"0", "ppid":"9521", "pid":"2547"
}

Essentially, just a bunch of keys that are to the left of an equal sign, and the value to the right, all separated by white space. PLEASE NOTE, I don't know what these keys will be. I won't have the same keys (like node, type, systemcall, etc) like i did in the above example, it depends on the data. Can NiFi be dynamic like this?

Comment: Can you show an example message and what you want the results to be?

Comment: Sure, sorry I actually meant to add this for you. Check my edit in my question.

Comment: @StudiousProgrammer, what should be the result? do you want to put those key-values into flow file attributes?

Comment: Yes, so in the flowfile, there should be an attribute for: node, type, systemcall, etc. I have a followup question, and wasn't sure if I should include it with this current post, but I'll add it here: Now that you know each 'key' should be an attribute for the flowfile, is it possible to put a prefix before each 'key' so the attribute would look something like "prefix-node, prefix-type, prefix-systemcall, etc". NOTE, this doesn't do anything for the value, just the attribute 'key' in the flowfile.

Comment: I suppose I should elaborate. I'm still very new to nifi, so I'm learning, and I'm hoping what I'm writing it both correct and the right way to go about with this data. Specifically, I want all my keys to be a part of my log. I'm essentially wanting to enrich my data so its easier to search and perform metrics. I won't know what these key/value pairs are with all my data. So they don't need to be attributes (but I'm assuming this would help), but they do need to be a part of the final json log I save.

Comment: @StudiousProgrammer, please edit your question and provide complete information  - what do you have as input, what do you expect as output... you also talking about json - what is it???

Comment: for dynamic behavior i see only script option...